# Наложение PictureBox поверх другого PictureBox C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть проблемы такая: есть основной PictureBox, в него идёт поток изображений с камеры (В виде видео), я хочу наложить сверху другой PictureBox, чтобы указывать какие либо статусы (Разрыв, нестабильное соединение и пр.). Соответственно я создал ещё один PB и задал ему BackColor = Transparent, присвоил ему изображение с прозрачным фоном .png, также добавил его к основному PB - PictBox.Controls.Add(Status), но вместо ожидаемой мной прозрачности, PB который был наложен сверху просвечивает основной PB аж до фонового изображения, игнорируя при этом видеопоток, и в итоге вместо того, чтобы наблюдать за видео и видеть наложенный сверху статус, мы видим видео, на котором квадрат, просвечивающий до фона и нужное нам изображение статуса. Может кто знает, как с этим бороться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparent

Comment: @Виктор Это уже было сделано. Это описано в основном сообщении

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910172/how-to-make-picturebox-transparent

Comment: @Виктор Спасибо, гляну

Comment: @Виктор Сделал по гайду новый элемент управления с отрисовкой, теперь отрисовывается правильно, но сам по себе уходит под PB, пытался исправить стандартными Drawing.BringToFront(), но не вышло, не знаете, как это победить?

Comment: Как вариант, менять регион (Region) верхнего PB, по форме изображения-статуса.

Comment: Надо не Drawing на фронт, а компонент, на котором Вы рисуете или если Вы рисуете на основном PictureBox, то сперва выводить на основной, а потом уже рисовать поверх что нужно

Comment: А просто в событии Paint первого пикчабокса рисовать этот png? Второй PB при этом не нужен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Я не уверен, как работает библиотека камеры с PB, поэтому не пробовал даже. Ещё раз, получается в событии Paint основного PB добавить дорисовку этого png? И если можно, то с примером, не до конца понимаю пока